# How to use GroupBy() in subqueries with LINQ?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, expression

I have pretty simple LINQ expression

```
IQueryable<FreeBetDTO> records = UnitOfWork.FreeBets
    .Include(f => f.FreeBetCategories)
    .Include(f => f.FreeBetCards)
    .Where(f => f.FreeBetCards.Any(cards => cards.UserId == request.UserId))
    .Select(f => new FreeBetDTO
    {
        FreeBetId = f.FreeBetId

        LineCategories = f.FreeBetCategories
            .GroupBy(g => new { g.LineCategoryID, g.Title })
            .Select(c =>
                new LineCategoryDTO
                {
                    LineCategoryID = c.Key.LineCategoryID,
                    Title = c.Key.Title
                }).AsEnumerable()
    });
```

When I am executing it I catch the error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to translate collection subquery in projection since it uses 'Distinct' or 'Group By' operations and doesn't project key columns of all of it's tables which are required to generate results on client side. Missing column: t.ID. Either add column(s) to the projection or rewrite query to not use 'GroupBy'/'Distinct' operation.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlExpressions.SelectExpression.

....
```

The problem is here `.GroupBy(g => new { g.LineCategoryID, g.Title })`. If I don't group records, the error disappears.
I was trying a lot of cases with `GroupBy()` and `Distinct()`. But can't understand why this is happening. Because I just need grouping like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error message says that you have to include `Id` column in projection. But you can't do that with `GroupBy`. So rewrite query into two steps (removed not needed includes):

```cs
var rawRecords = UnitOfWork.FreeBets
    .Where(f => f.FreeBetCards.Any(cards => cards.UserId == request.UserId))
    .Select(f => new 
    {
        FreeBetId = f.FreeBetId
        LineCategories = f.FreeBetCategories.Select(c => new { c.Id, c.LineCategoryID, c.Title })
            .ToList()
    })
    .AsEnumerable();

var records = rawRecords
    .Select(f => new FreeBetDTO
    {
        FreeBetId = f.FreeBetId
        LineCategories = f.LineCategories.GroupBy(g => new { g.LineCategoryID, g.Title })
            .Select(c =>
                new LineCategoryDTO
                {
                    LineCategoryID = c.Key.LineCategoryID,
                    Title = c.Key.Title
                })
    });
```

Similar query, but more optimal:

```cs
var query =
    from f in UnitOfWork.FreeBets
    from c in f.FreeBetCards
    where f.FreeBetCards.Any(cards => cards.UserId == request.UserId)
    select new { f.FreeBetId, c.LineCategoryID, c.Title };

query = query.Distinct();

var records = query.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(f => f.FreeBetId)
    .Select(g => new FreeBetDTO
    {
        FreeBetId = g.Key
        LineCategories = g.Select(c =>
                new LineCategoryDTO
                {
                    LineCategoryID = c.LineCategoryID,
                    Title = c.Title
                })
            .AsEnumerable()
    });
```

Comment: Good solution! It solves my problem. But `.GroupBy()` works on client side now, because of `.AsEnumerable()` called on `rawRecords`. Do you know how to force it to work on server side?

Comment: Well I have better solution. Moment.

Comment: Added another sample. But grouping you have to do on the client side also. Positive moment that it is more effective query.